# Do /etc/resolver/ files work in Mountain Lion for DNS resolution?

Tags: macos, dns

Can anyone tell me if adding a file under /etc/resolver will work for DNS resolution using a DNS server other than what is handed out via DHCP ?

My issue is that I want to use OpenDNS for a clients home DNS resolution in order to take advantage of the filtering and anti scam capabilities but the massive disadvantage is that here in Australia things such as Apple content are delivered by a CDN (Akamai) which will then server content using a US based delivery point.

What I want to do is have the DNS server address handed out via DHCP to be the local router address (DNSMasq using OpenDNS DNS servers) and then, for example, place a file called apple.com under /etc/resolver with the following line:

```
nameserver 203.12.160.35
```

The idea is that any DNS request to apple.com would be resolved by a TPG (my ISP) DNS server rather than the local routers DNSMasq daemon using OpenDNS servers.

So I have done this and the output of **scutil --dns** is:

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : harland
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.10.1
  nameserver[1] : 192.168.10.1
  if_index : 4 (en2)
  reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 301000

resolver #8
  domain   : apple.com
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : harland
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.10.1
  nameserver[1] : 192.168.10.1
  if_index : 4 (en2)
  flags    : Scoped
  reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address
macbookair:resolver
```

Now the output of an nslookup on apple.com is:

```
macbookair:resolver ilium007$ nslookup apple.com
Server:     192.168.10.1
Address:    192.168.10.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   apple.com
Address: 17.149.160.49
Name:   apple.com
Address: 17.172.224.47

macbookair:resolver
```

So I am not using the TPG DNS server - I am still resolving against 192.168.10.1 which is the local router. Does the order of the resolvers matter ? ie. the entry created after I place the apple.com file in /etc/resolver is resolver #8:

```
resolver #8
  domain   : apple.com
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
```

I would really like a way to make this work - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 50):

This question seems a bit old, but I'm going to answer it anyways as I had a similar problem:

**Yes, this works.**

Your **first problem** is that you obviously have the wrong IP (`8.8.8.8` instead of `203.12.160.35`) in `/etc/resolver/apple.com`. Verify that the contents of this file is really:

```
nameserver 203.12.160.35
```

Then `scutil --dns` should have an entry like this:

```
resolver #8
  domain   : apple.com
  nameserver[0] : 203.12.160.35
```

The **second problem** is that you tried to verify it using `nslookup` which does not use the DNS resolution mechanisms of OS X. If you look at the man page of `nslookup` you will find this:

```
Mac OS X NOTICE
   The nslookup command does not use the host name and address resolution or the DNS 
   query routing mechanisms used by other processes running on Mac OS X.  The results of 
   name or address queries printed by nslookup may differ from those found by other
   processes that use the Mac OS X native name and address resolution mechanisms. The 
   results of DNS queries may also differ from queries that use the Mac OS X DNS routing 
   library.
```

To **check your DNS config** you could do

```
dns-sd -G v4 images.apple.com
```

and verify if it yields the same IP as

```
nslookup images.apple.com 203.12.160.35
```

Comment: It's also worth noting this can be used to specify a nameserver for a specific top level domain. For example if file is named "dev" then all lookups  for "example.dev" will be sent to that nameserver. This is useful for company intranets, especially when you're not on the company LAN (eg: when connecting to a VPN)

Comment: `Your first problem is that you obviously have the wrong IP (8.8.8.8)` Not necessarily; `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are Google's DNS servers. How they obtained those octets is beyond me.

Comment: As of 10.10, it seems that there is no /etc/resolver directory present.

Comment: You need to create it yourself in 10.10.

Comment: @apfelsaft - Is it possible to configure the resolver to use a different port than 53 or 5353?

Answer (score 16):

Using resolver files is actually not the recommended way of doing that.
Instead you should create DNS resolver with `scutil`.

To see all DNS queries on interface `en0`, open a Terminal and run:

```
sudo tcpdump -n -i en0 port 53
```

Open another Terminal window and run:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
ping apple.stackexchange.com -c1
```

The first two lines flush your DNS cache, so the system has to send out a request for sure. Why `ping`? `ping` uses the normal system APIs to resolve DNS names; unlike `host`, `dig`, and `nslookup` that do all DNS resolution on their own, so that they can query arbitrary DNS servers and not just those configured in the system.

You should see in `tcpdump` that your standard DNS server is queried, right?

Well, let's change that:

```
sudo scutil
d.init
d.add ServerAddresses * 9.9.9.9
d.add SupplementalMatchDomains * stackexchange.com
set State:/Network/Service/whatever-you-want-as-long-as-unique/DNS
```

You can quit that interactive `scutil` console either with `quit` or by hitting CTRL+C.

Now try the DNS flush and ping again and watch what `tcpdump` says. It says that `9.9.9.9` is queried! Well, check out `scutil --dns`:

```
resolver #2
  domain   : stackexchange.com
  nameserver[0] : 9.9.9.9
  flags    : Supplemental, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
  order    : 101000
```

See, you got a new resolver. Also note that `stackexchange.com` has been added to the search domain list of your primary resolver (#1). This allows you to

```
# ping apple
PING apple.stackexchange.com (151.101.65.69): 56 data bytes
```

Sweet. Now lets get rid of it again:

```
sudo scutil
remove State:/Network/Service/whatever-you-want-as-long-as-unique/DNS
```

That's basically it. A couple of notes:

- You can add multiple DNS servers and search domains separated by space,
  e.g. `d.add ServerAddresses * 9.9.9.9 8.8.8.8`
- You can see what you've configured so far with `d.show`
- `whatever-you-want-as-long-as-unique` means that every service must have a unique ID. Apple uses UUIDs for that but you can in fact really use anything as long as it won't conflict with existing services (and it cannot contain `/` as that's the separator character). To see what already exists, just use `list` and to see the content of an existing key use `show <key>`
- Your global DNS settings, those found in `/etc/resolv.conf`, are in fact from `scutil`, checkout `show State:/Network/Global/DNS`. If you change that key, the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` will change accordingly. But you shouldn't ever do so, as this key is managed by the system and will be overwritten on various occasions (pretty much any network change, DHCP renew, etc.)
- To see what other commands exist, use `help`.
- `sudo scutil` is only required if you want to change keys. Reading keys is also possible as normal user.

BTW: `9.9.9.9` is [Quad9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad9). It's like `8.8.8.8` but guarantees your privacy (no IP addresses are ever logged) and tries to protect you by not resolving known malicious domains. Whereas 8.8.8.8 logs your IP address and keeps that information for for 24 to 48 hours, [see here](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/privacy).

Comment: Is it possible to configure the `scutil`-based resolver to use a different port than 53 or 5353?

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh Not per server but it should be possible per resolver: `d.add ServerPort # 1234` (will then apply to all servers of that resolver). The `#` is important as otherwise it would be a string value, yet according to documentation it must be a numeric value.

Comment: For anyone wanting to do this from bash as a script `echo "f.read script.txt" | sudo scutil`

Comment: There are at least three modern (that is, not /etc/resolv.conf or /etc/hosts) ways to edit Mac DNS: 1) networksetup, 2) scutil, and 3) /etc/resolver/ files. In what order does MacOS check these? Is one of them considered more correct to use than the others?

Comment: @knite `networksetup` is just a wrapper around `scutil`, `ifconfig`, `route`, etc. As you can read on its man page, it's just the CLI version of the network settings in System Preferences, where you can also configure your DNS - but all of that ends up in the Dynamic Store and that's what `scutil` manipulates directly. `/etc/resolver` is only kept for backward compatibility with (Free)BSD and only used by some tools/APIs as a fallback to the Dynamic Store. Since macOS 10.4 (Tiger), the Dynamic Store is where the real system network settings are found.

Comment: I'm trying to find where I could learn more about this grammar.. Like, what does the star in `ServerAddresses * 9.9.9.9` and SupplementalMatchDomains mean? What are valid properties? I found https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf but it unfortunately looks more helpful than it is

Comment: @djeikyb Asking an own question would make it way easier to provide you with answers, that's not what comments are for. The `*` is part of `scutil` syntax and it means that `ServerAddress` is of type array (it could contain multiple values, though in my example I only has a single one); without it it would be a string. Run `scutil` and then type `help`. See `d.add key [*#?%] val [v2 ...]`.

Comment: @djeikyb `SupplementalMatchDomains` means that these are additional match domains that will apply without replacing your normal match domains and that are also active without switching to that DNS responder. Note that the entire DNS code of macOS is open source: https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aapple-oss-distributions+SupplementalMatchDomains&type=code

Comment: Makes sense! Asked: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452191/whats-the-grammar-of-the-dynamic-stores-dns-config

Comment: Ha. I looked at the text of help before commenting and did *not* understand the first parameter is declaring the type of the rest

Comment: @Mecki your post is gold!
Are you aware of any Apple official docs or maybe third party resources that explain in detail all the functionality in `scutil`?

Also, would you know if there are system APIs that a developer could use to write a small application that provides a UI for these kinds of changes?

Comment: @GabrielC The API to access the storage that `scutil` manipulates is called `SCDynamicStore` and it's part of the `SystemConfiguartion` framework. https://0cn.de/h368 It even allows you to monitor keys there for changes and get notifications if the system or the user or other apps make changes. Here's code that dumps the entire store content: https://pastebin.com/gWDeDNqG It uses very modern Obj-C syntax but could also have used Swift instead: https://pastebin.com/GRPsPxpV

Comment: I don't see this easy at all. I prefer GNU style to this.