# Yosemite /etc/resolver/env.domain.com not working

Tags: macos, dns

We have a site to site VPN connection setup in the office to two development networks

- dev
- stage

I want to be able to let people in the office not be on VPN for dns resolution to work. Each environment also has its own dns server. So I can't give the whole office a single dns server via dhcp and call it a day.

I tried the following

```
echo 'nameserver 10.122.3.10' > /etc/resolver/dev.domain.com 
echo 'nameserver 10.121.3.10' > /etc/resolver/stage.domain.com
```

the OS seems to be picking it up

```
ip-10-1-1-116:~ username$ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : google.com
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.4.4
  if_index : 4 (en0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable

resolver #2
  domain   : stage.domain.com
  nameserver[0] : 10.121.3.10
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : google.com
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.4.4
  if_index : 4 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : Reachable
```

The issue is I can't resolve anything on the stage.domain.com domain search

```
ip-10-1-1-116:resolver username$ nslookup mongo-arb.stage.domain.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find mongo-arb.stage.domain.com: NXDOMAIN
```

I can hit it going right to the server

```
ip-10-1-1-116:resolver username$ nslookup mongo-arb.stage.domain.com 10.121.3.10
Server:     10.121.3.10
Address:    10.121.3.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mongo-arb.stage.domain.com
Address: 10.121.15.116
```

**EDIT**

I'm using 10.10.4

Answer (score 1):

You could see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/82006/31154) why `nslookup` does not work.

To check your configuration, try instead:

```
dns-sd -G v4 mongo-arb.stage.domain.com
```