# macOS High Sierra not trying other DNS servers

Tags: macos, high-sierra, dns

On one of my laptops which is running macOS High Sierra, is failing to resolve hostnames. I have specified two DNS servers in my network settings. One is an internal DNS server, and the other is 8.8.8.8. When I try to resolve local hostnames that the internal DNS knows, it resolves properly. But when I try to resolve something like google.com it fails.

I see that it tries to use the internal DNS server first, and since it doesn't know the hostname, I thought it would try to use 8.8.8.8 to resolve the hostname, but it never tries the other DNS server.

When I try this from my other laptop, it works properly i see

```
$>nslookup google.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from <internal dns>, trying next server
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.5.110
```

But from the one where it doesn't I see

```
$>nslookup google.com
Server:        <internal dns>
Address:    <internal dns>#53

** server can’t find google.com: SERVFAIL
```

There is no attempt to try the 8.8.8.8 DNS server. Why is that happening? How can I get it to try the other DNS server if it fails with one.

Answer (score 7):

First: `nslookup` does not use the system DNS resolver, and does not behave the same way that the system resolver does. Neither do `dig` or `host`, so none of these tools are useful for checking how macOS resolves names. If you want to use the system resolver, use `dscacheutil -q host -a name google.com`, but note that it uses the entire resolution system -- it looks in the local cache, /etc/hosts, mDNS (for .local names), and then DNS. Oh, and the man page for `dscacheutil` claims it can flush the DNS cache, but it doesn't work; use `sudo killall mDNSResponder` instead.

Second: the system resolver does not do a good (or even adequate) job of failing over between DNS servers. If you list multiple servers, it'll fire off queries to all of them in a sort of randomized-round-robin fashion. If it doesn't get a response, it'll eventually time out and try the other one. If it gets a "that doesn't exist" response, it assumes that's correct and doesn't try any other server. As a result, you really need a single server that can answer all queries, both internal and external.

Ok, there's one possible workaround: you can point your system at a public DNS server, then create /etc/resolver/ and put files in it to redirect queries for certain domains to your internal server. Provided you know what domains to redirect, that is. See [Apple.SE: "Do /etc/resolver/ files work in Mountain Lion for DNS resolution?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74639/do-etc-resolver-files-work-in-mountain-lion-for-dns-resolution).